# ¿Cómo puedo desplegar toda una sentencia de instrucciones en IntelliJ IDEA en el lenguaje de Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

Lo que sucede es que en un video tutorial note que la persona escribio un bloque de sentencias para el uso de When sin tener que escribir cada una de las constantes. Me gustaria saber que teclas utilizo para ese atajo de teclado, espero puedan contestar mi duda, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta presionando `TAB` cuando escribas el `when(tipoDeDato)` pero solo funcionara cuando el intelisense pueda conocer el tipo de dato al cual va a generar.

Por ejemplo el intelisense puede generar el when completo de un enum ya que si es posible descubrir todas sus propiedades en tiempo de compilacion pero no te funcionara si el tipo de dato es un `int`, `string` u otro tipo de dato que solo se puede descubrir en tiempo de ejecucion.

Comment: muchas gracias:3